# MongoDb direct client connections

Tags: c#, mongodb, appserver

I have a c# client application which connects directly to a Mongodb server with the 10gen c# driver. In terms of pure number of connections that can be held is it sensible to have clients connect directly to the db? Could too many clients swamp the db and crash it? is it more sensible to always use an app server to process db read write requests?

Answer (score 0):

As the [wiki](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Quickstart#CSharpDriverQuickstart-YoudoNOTneedtocallConnectorDisconnect) says:

> The C# driver has a connection pool to use connections to the server
>   efficiently. There is no need to call Connect or Disconnect; just let
>   the driver take care of the connections (calling Connect is harmless,
>   but calling Disconnect is bad because it closes all the connections in
>   the connection pool).